# Maintain position of navigation links when one or more is absent

Tags: html, css

I have a simple blog with three navigation links - next, archive and previous. The engine that renders the blog will leave out either the next or previous links when no next or previous post exists. Is there a way to ensure that the removal or either will not affect the placement of the other two?

I've tried several methods but my archive link always drifts off center in the direction of the absent link.

**Edit:** More info below in response to Blender. Apologies for no live demo. I'll see what I can do.

My first attempt was just a list displayed inline and centered in the main div of the page. Then I tried breaking it apart and floating next and previous to the left and right of archive, which worked well when all three were present but caused the drift described above. What I want is for the links to be horizontally aligned but independent of each other, with archive always centered in the div.

From my mako template, the latter attempt (with the floats):

```
<div id="navigation">
% if prev_post:
    <a id="prev" href="${prev_post.permapath()}">&#60;&#60;Prev</a>
% endif
% if next_post:
    <a id="next" href="${next_post.permapath()}">Next&#62;&#62;</a>
% endif
    <a id="archive" href="/archive">Archive</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Without any visualization of the problem (a live demo is preferred), there's no way anyone can help you.

Comment: To expand on @Blender 's comment, we need to know what HTML is rendered by the blog engine for the navigation links. Preferably when all 3 elements are present and when they are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your code so that instead of removing the element, just remove the text:

```
<div id="navigation">

    <a id="prev" href="${prev_post.permapath()}"> % if prev_post: &#60;&#60; Prev% endif </a>


    <a id="next" href="${next_post.permapath()}"> % if next_post: Next&#62;&#62; % endif </a>

    <a id="archive" href="/archive">Archive</a>
</div>
```

Now you can set a width on the anchors using CSS.

```
a {
    width: 60px; 
    height: 20px;   
    display: block; 
    float:left;    
}
```

Don't forget you'll need to clear the div as it contains floated elements.

Check out this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GcpJA/.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I also used `text-align: center;` to center the nav links within their respective boxes. Height is also a crucial property because without it, the other floats push right through it. And for users of mako, control statements are only valid if they are the first text on the line, though they can be preceded by an arbitrary number of spaces.